# What is the right behavior for http://anonymous.invalid?

Tags: dns, chrome, browser

When I browse to

- http://anonymous.invalid

Google Chromium actually redirects me to a google search for `anonymous.invalid`. Is this the right behavior, per the spec? I would have expected this to generate a 404 error in the browser. The [`.invalid`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.invalid) domain is described as

> ".invalid" is intended for use in online construction of domain names that are sure to be invalid and which it is obvious at a glance are invalid.

For comparison when I go to

- http://Dywred8Shleks.com

It gives me an error.

> This site can’t be reached `dywred8shleks.com’s` server IP address could not be found.
>   Try:
>
> Checking the connection
>
> Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS configuration
>
> `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

I just wanted `anonymous.invalid` to be more safe (against registration) and to articulate intent.

Comment: Possibly related: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2782285?hl=en

Comment: @Jesse_b not sure that's related, I tried to clarify in the update.

Comment: Well it seems like your address bar **is** doing a google search so it is sort of related in that sense, and apparently there are no settings to configure this.  Why it is doing the search is still unanswered.

Comment: that dywred url doesn't give _me_ a 404.  be specific about your errors.  DNS not resolve is not the same as 404.  I don't think you're getting a 404 in any of your responses; a 404 is a response from a webserver, and you'd have to resolve those names before contacting a webserver.

Comment: Spec? There is no spec for what a browser is to do when given an string in the **search** box. There is an spec for what a DNS server should answer, if that is what you are asking. Are you asking about DNS spec?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Linux. The behavior comes from your web browser and is the same on other, non-Linux OSes. See e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/354338/force-chrome-to-open-urls-as-urls-instead-of-searching (SU would be a much better place for your question but there's no migration path to there)

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug in Chrome. As a link this does not result in a Google Search. Only when pasted into the URL bar itself can this behavior be seen.

I filed this as a bug

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1008918

Comment: Honestly that seems expected.  I wouldn't expect google to perform a search for a hyperlink that you clicked on but would expect it to perform one on a custom search.

Comment: when you paste the other nonresolving url in the box, it comes up with a name resolution error.  Perhaps the `.invalid` is treated specially, as the spec specifically says it will never resolve

Answer (score 1):

[FROM Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.invalid)

The name invalid is reserved by the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) in RFC 2606 (June 1999) as a domain name that may not be installed as a top-level domain in the Domain Name System (DNS) of the Internet.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.invalid)

If you like to use, for example, http://anonymous.evan just add / at the end.
Then google chrome tries to solve it.

EDIT: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30636
Got the info from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783705/force-chrome-to-follow-url-and-not-search/36783847#36783847

Comment: http://anonymous.evan/ also does a google search. I would expect that because `.evan` could be a valid.

Comment: http://anonymous.jaur/ does not do the search, it tries to solved it.
Version: Version 76.0.3809.100 (Developer Build) built on Debian 10.0, running on Debian 10.1 (64-bit)
For example: anonymous.jaur123456 browser will do the search, http://anonymous.jaur123456 + / and browser will try to solve that address.

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

There are many standards that codify how to interpret a URL. But there are no standards that codify how to interpret a string typed in the combined URL-and-search bar of a web browser.

There is an unwritten expectation that when you type a valid URL in the bar, the browser visits the URL. However, the exact definition of “valid” is up to interpretation. Major browsers have heuristics to decide whether a string looks like a URL or something else (for example a search or a bookmarklet).

[RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) specifies that the top-level domain `invalid` will never be assigned on the Internet. It doesn't codify what people might do on a private network (intranet). The rationale in the document speaks against using it on a private network, but RFCs only regulate the Internet, not private networks.

It is reasonable for Chromium to treat `invalid` as an ordinary top-level domain and let the DNS system handle RFC 2606 by never returning any records under `.invalid`. It is also reasonable for Chromium to decide that `.invalid` is never a valid TLD and treat anything that looks like a URL with this TLD as not a URL.

There are a few constraints that web browsers should follow regarding URL construction. For example, [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) specifies that certain site names must not be accessed over HTTP, only over HTTPS, so it would be wrong for a web browser to treat `facebook.com` as a shortcut for `http://facebook.com` rather than `https://facebook.com`¹. But no such constraint applies to `.invalid`, merely a permission to treat it differently from ordinary TLD.

¹  <sub>The details of how HSTS works are out of scope of this answer.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The correct behavior in the [Chromium omnibox](https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/omnibox) is to search, because anything typed into the location bar that [doesn't use a TLD](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30636#c39) from [this list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat) gets sent as a search term.

The list is included in chromium source code (at least in version 73 for Debian oldstable as I retrieved with `apt-get source chromium`) in `net/base/registry_controlled_domains/effective_tld_names.dat`. You could try rebuilding Chromium with the additional TLDs you care about added to that file.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be the DNS server: The DNS server provided by many ISPs will re-direct when given a name that it can not find. Often to some advertisement, or bogo-help.

Comment: It's not that in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not even a DNS question. Google Chrome will search for terms that it thinks are not host names, DNS names or IPs. It's pretty particular about this. For example http://127.0.0.1 will not search but http://256.0.0.1 will because its out of range for an IP. While .invalid TLD is definitely a domain name even if its not valid to register one. Resolving to 404 doesn't make any sense because this is a HTTP error and there's no way to resolve the DNS name. The correct error message would be `Name not resolvable, record does not exist`. Or `Name not resolvable, invalid records will not be forwarded`. I agree with the OP that this is incorrect behavior. Also note that http://site.example and http://site.test DO NOT search.